# Ruby extracting array values

Tags: ruby, arrays, concatenation

I want to extract certain values from one array and concat them into another empty one:

```
freqs=[1,12,4,15,7,8,11,5,6]
less_freqs=[]
```

This is what I've come up with.

```
freqs.collect{|x| x<9 then x.to_a{|y|less_freqs<<y}}
```

Perhaps a different method? And, I'm not even sure if `then` makes any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
freqs = [1,12,4,15,7,8,11,5,6]
less_freqs = freqs.select{|x| x < 9 } # => [1, 4, 7, 8, 5, 6]
```

Comment: yes, though additionally I would like to push it into the less_freqs array